# How to i use id from a selected item in datatable for a button?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem with **PHP** and **Codeigniter**. In this datatable, you can select rows from it. What I need to do, is that when I select a row, I have to use it's `id` to press the yellow button call *'**editar**'* at right and be available to edit that row.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbD1f.png)

this is my **HTML**:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        <?=$tablaObrasSociales?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="ibox">
            <div class="ibox-content" style="text-align: center;">
                <h3>Acciones</h3>
                <p><button class="btn btn-w-m btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalNuevaOS" ><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Obra Social</button></p>
                <p><button id="btnEditarOs" onclick="accionClickObrasSociales();" class="btn btn-w-m btn-warning" disabled data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditarOS"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Editar</button></p>
                <p><button id="btnBajaOs" class="btn btn-w-m btn-danger" disabled><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Dar de baja</button></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this my **Javascript**:

```
 function accionClickObrasSociales(){
        var id_fila=$(this).attr('id');
        $('#tablaObrasSociales tr').removeClass("filaResaltada"); //Limpia el estilo de fila resaltada
        $(this).addClass("filaResaltada"); //Resalta la fila seleccionada
        if (id_fila != null) {
          document.getElementById("btnEditarOs").disabled = false;
          document.getElementById("btnBajaOs").disabled = false;
        }
        editar(id_fila);
    }

function editar(idFila){
  debugger;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?= BASEURL?>" + "/obraSocial/editar/"+idFila,
  });
}
```

Comment: You can add a data-attribute to each row as a target for id in your database, you can try `data-id=id`

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the row data to get the selected row id :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

function accionClickObrasSociales(){
    var id_fila=$(this).attr('id');
    $('#tablaObrasSociales tr').removeClass("filaResaltada"); //Limpia el estilo de fila resaltada
    $(this).addClass("filaResaltada"); //Resalta la fila seleccionada
    if (id_fila != null) {
      document.getElementById("btnEditarOs").disabled = false;
      document.getElementById("btnBajaOs").disabled = false;
    }
    editar(id_fila);

    var selected_id = $.map(table.rows('.selected').data(), function (item) {
        return item[0] // return first column value, which is ID column
    });
    console.log('the row id is : ', selected_id)
}
```